# How do I preserve literals when passing from Python to C++ and back to Python

Tags: c++, python

Ok, here's the deal.  I have a program that makes a log in Python.  I wanted this log to be secure from edits when the program isn't using it, so I wrote a python script which creates C++ source designed to reprint the log back into Python.  Once I compile this source, I can have the log pretty secure, then just run the executable to retrieve it.  Its convoluted, but it works

**The Issue:** When I create the Python log, I replace `'` with the equivalent literal (`\'`) so that it doesn't ruin my strings while their stored.  But, when I pick this up with C++, and the plop it back down, I lose the literal, so I get broken strings.  Is there an easy way to replace the `'` in C++ with the corresponding literal similar to the `replace` function in Python.

**Some code snippets that might help:**

How I write string to the log in Python

```
logFile.write("    '{}'".format(somestring.replace("'","\\'").encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

What the Python log looks like:

```
CRDict = {"ID number string":[list of a bunch of items], "Another ID number: [Another list of things]}
```

How I write the C++ lines that store strings from the log in Python (where CR{} is `struct`)

```
CFile.write('    CR{}.somestring = "{}";\n'.format(num,somestring))
```

What the C++ line that stores the string ends up looking like

```
CR0.somestring = "This is a string and it doesn't keep track of literals";
```

The C++ line which writes the string back into Python (the file called `CRPYLog`)

```
CRPYLog << "    '" + CR0.somestring + "'," << endl;
```

And this is what the line looks like when it gets printed back into the Python log

```
'This is a string and it doesn't keep track of literals'
```

The above line is not syntactically valid, so it will break when I try to use the Python log

Comment: Why do you need to replace it? Python read files in 'raw' mode by default. Having quotes inside it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: That doesn't look any more secure than a plaintext log. Anyone who can read or run your C++ can read your log.

Comment: Also, unless you're trying to make the log valid Python source code (which you shouldn't), none of this escaping is necessary. (If you are, none of this escaping is sufficient.)

Comment: @alkid, I need to replace them because any single quotes writtin in the string will make Python think the string ends early.  ```'This is all in the string ` this isn't even though I want it to be'```  So any contraction or text quotes wont be stored properly

Comment: @user2357112 By "Secure" I meant safe from edit, I'll update the post to make that more clear.  And why shouldn't I try to valid python source code?

Comment: First, why wouldn't anyone be able to edit your C++? Second, it is far easier and safer to make a file with log text in it than to make a file containing Python source code with a string literal in it that evaluates to a log. Suppose someone makes their username `Robert\'+exec("""import os; os.system("shutdown")""")#`. You'll backslash-escape the single quote, but the backslash in the username will escape your backslash, and the log file will shut down the computer when imported.

Comment: The semantics of it aren't really important for this quesiton, BUT, all the editing of the log is handled by the program, usernames are read from the system, and sure, I suppose if people want to try to edit the compiled C++ code, they're welcome to try.  And I have checks to make sure they don't use they're own C++ source to replace the executable.  Now, if you're quite done, any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: _"I wanted this log to be secure from edits when the program isn't using it"_ Then you either want to encrypt the file and/or add a digital signature to it. Apparantly, I don't "get the deal" from your question?

Comment: @moooeeeep I tried playing with permissions, but I haven't looked into encryption, are there any good resources for doing that easily in Python?

Comment: @wnnmaw How come it didn't work with permissions?

Comment: @moooeeeep All users need to be able to be to edit the log via the script, but not all users have admin rights which allow them to alter the permissions (because the permission of the script depends on the permission of the user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to address what seems to be your primary goal, i.e., to make your application's *"log to be secure from edits when the program isn't using it"*, I would suggest to stick with commonly used standard tools that were made for purposes alike.

For example, add a [*digital signature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature):

> A digital signature is a mathematical scheme for demonstrating the authenticity of a digital message or document. A valid digital signature gives a recipient reason to believe that the message was created by a known sender, such that the sender cannot deny having sent the message (authentication and non-repudiation) and that the message was not altered in transit (integrity). Digital signatures are commonly used for software distribution, financial transactions, and in other cases where it is important to detect forgery or tampering.

and/or [encrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) the file:

> In cryptography, encryption is the process of encoding messages (or information) in such a way that third parties cannot read it, but only authorized parties can.

Both approaches are cryptographic ways to make it very hard to alter the file content undetectedly, if the used (private) encryption key is effectively kept secret.

---

In Python you could use [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.de/) ([python-gnupg](http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/index.html)) for both approaches:

> The gnupg module allows Python programs to make use of the functionality provided by the GNU Privacy Guard (abbreviated GPG or GnuPG). Using this module, Python programs can encrypt and decrypt data, digitally sign documents and verify digital signatures, manage (generate, list and delete) encryption keys, using proven Public Key Infrastructure (PKI) encryption technology based on OpenPGP.

I haven't used this Python library myself, but GnuPG itself is somewhat standard, e.g., for securing e-mail communication or linux package distribution.

Note that you might need a digital signature even though you have encrypted the file this way. That's because a [public key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is being used for the encryption, that is by definition public. In asymmetric cryptography you need the (secret) private key to decode the ciphertext and to create a digital signature, that is to authenticate the identity of the recipient (encryption) and the sender (signature).

---

If you want to go with encryption plus integrity check, have a look at this library:

- https://cryptography.io/en/latest/

---

That is, when the protection provided by your operating system's access control mechanisms suffice, you could just configure them restrictively and rely on that. (No need for passphrase checks then either.)

Comment: I tried playing with encryption yesterday after you mentioned it, and I like it a lot better than c++. However, I hit some issues using pyDes. Basically I encrypted each line, then save it to a text file. But when I go to read it and decrypt, it fails. I think this is because the encryption uses new line characters and end of file marks in its encryption. I'll take a look at the module you suggested today

Comment: GnuPG is way to much for me, but I got the solution in your first link to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Is there an easy way to replace the ' in C++ with the corresponding literal similar to the replace function in Python.**

Actually yes, you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) libraries for that.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp> 

std::string some_string("Your string");
boost::replace_all(some_string, "Your", "My");
```